# Is there a word such that it is the version of "anachronism" when "time" is replaced with "occasion"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I wonder if there is single word in English that is the version of "anachronism" with "time" replaced with "occasion". I recall that I saw such a word somewhere; but I am not really sure.

To supplement,
as far as I can tell the word "anachronism" describes (roughly speaking) occurrences in a wrong time. I would like to know a word that describes occurrences in a wrong occasion. For example, one wears a suit to sleep.

Comment: I do not understand your question. So you mean: anachronism is to time as occasion is to [x]?

Comment: @Lambie, Hi, thanks for feedback. I added an example to clarify.

Comment: I think you mean "anachronism". Only one "r".

Comment: Anachronism is thing in the present that comes from the past. It is out of place,historically. What you know describe though is a bungled act. :)

Answer (score 1):

[incongruous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incongruous)

> incongruous, adjective
>
> uk /ɪnˈkɒŋ.ɡru.əs/
>
> us /ɪnˈkɑːŋ.ɡru.əs/ ​
>
> unusual or different from what is around or from what is generally
>   happening:
>
> "The new computer looked incongruous in the dark book-filled library."
>
> "It seems incongruous to have a woman as the editor of a men's
>   magazine."

Answer (score 1):

A possible phrase is **out of place**.

> Hiking boots are **out of place** at a formal dance.

Though it is not a noun, like *anachronism*.  I'm not sure there's a word for "an out of place thing", except perhaps *incongruity*, to borrow from the answer by Duckisaduckisaduck which offers **incongruous**.

Another possibility which comes close is **impropriety**, which refers to something that is wrong for the occasion, a breach of decorum.  But it's a value judgment, unlike *anachronism*, which is based in fact, not values.